# Tracing cause of NSRangeException - exception breakpoint always returns to `int main(int argc, char * argv[])`

Tags: objective-c, xcode6, interface-builder

I've been stuck on this all day, and struggling to identify the source of a NSRangeException crash.

The app builds fine, but in the process of loading the first scene it throws:

```
2015-05-01 17:21:48.606 AppName[3707:447852] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 4 beyond bounds [0 .. 3]'
```

The full stack trace is:

```
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111d22c65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000111584bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111c0c093 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 227
3   UIKit                               0x000000010f311881 _UIViewTopDownSubtreeTraversal + 193
4   UIKit                               0x000000010f932fa3 -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout_EngineDelegate) _invalidateSystemLayoutSizeFittingSizeAtEngineDelegateLevel] + 141
5   Foundation                          0x000000010e931d6f -[NSISEngine tryToAddConstraintWithMarker:expression:integralizationAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 915
6   Foundation                          0x000000010eabc1e8 -[NSLayoutConstraint _addLoweredExpression:toEngine:integralizationAdjustment:lastLoweredConstantWasRounded:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 275
7   Foundation                          0x000000010e92649a -[NSLayoutConstraint _addToEngine:integralizationAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 220
8   UIKit                               0x000000010f92fa34 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke_2 + 474
9   Foundation                          0x000000010e9341be -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 155
10  UIKit                               0x000000010f92f83a __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke + 452
11  UIKit                               0x000000010f92f64d -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:] + 197
12  UIKit                               0x000000010f92f933 __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke_2 + 217
13  Foundation                          0x000000010e9341be -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 155
14  UIKit                               0x000000010f92f83a __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke + 452
15  UIKit                               0x000000010f92f64d -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:] + 197
16  UIKit                               0x000000010f92f2de -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _initializeHostedLayoutEngine] + 404
17  UIKit                               0x000000010f92426e -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _layoutEngine_windowDidChange] + 126
18  UIKit                               0x000000010f32f561 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 209
19  UIKit                               0x000000010f32f74a -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 698
20  UIKit                               0x000000010f327ecf __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 125
21  UIKit                               0x000000010f327e43 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 437
22  UIKit                               0x000000010f331f48 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1660
23  UIKit                               0x000000010f61884c -[UINavigationTransitionView transition:fromView:toView:] + 479
24  UIKit                               0x000000010f4161b0 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 2984
25  UIKit                               0x000000010f416448 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 523
26  UIKit                               0x000000010f416f0e -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 43
27  UIKit                               0x000000010f561715 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 202
28  UIKit                               0x000000010f334a2b -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 536
29  QuartzCore                          0x000000010eff4ec2 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 146
30  QuartzCore                          0x000000010efe96d6 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
31  QuartzCore                          0x000000010efe9546 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
32  QuartzCore                          0x000000010ef55886 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 242
33  QuartzCore                          0x000000010ef56a3a _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 462
34  UIKit                               0x000000010f2b2a2d -[UIApplication _reportMainSceneUpdateFinished:] + 44
35  UIKit                               0x000000010f2b36f1 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 2648
36  UIKit                               0x000000010f2b20d5 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 179
37  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001158955e5 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke_2 + 21
38  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111c5641c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
39  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111c4c165 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
40  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111c4b923 __CFRunLoopRun + 851
41  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111c4b366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
42  UIKit                               0x000000010f2b1b42 -[UIApplication _run] + 413
43  UIKit                               0x000000010f2b4900 UIApplicationMain + 1282
44  My360                               0x000000010dcf26ff main + 111
45  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001127f5145 start + 1
46  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
```

It's a large app, and I cannot identify which `objectAtIndex` is causing the issue.

After looking at similar issues, I added an Exception breakpoint:

[image]

However the breakpoint just keeps taking me back to the main.m file:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
@autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
}
```

Can anyone point me towards how I can identify the line that is causing this exception?

Thanks!

Edit:

When I click on the My360 icon at the top of the debugging console, it shows this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: When you click on My360, what does it show?

Comment: Hi doug - sorry to sound like a noob, but wasn't quite sure where I should click on My360. Have posted a guess in an edit above - is this what you meant?

Comment: In your stack trace on the left side of your window when the exception occurs. When you click it you should see the line in that file that caused the issue. Any other files you see in the stack trace that are yours should show similar results.

Comment: @DougWatkins - ah, I see what you mean. Have added a screeenshot above. When I open that trace, and click on the highlighted row ('12 main'), it takes me to the main.m file, with the `int main(int argc, char * argv[])` method mentioned in the original post. But from there, I can't be sure where this is being called from.

Comment: add the exception breakpoint. At the bottom of the list of break points click the plus icon then add exception breakpoint. This should show you the line to look at.

Comment: When you add it, it will show up in the list as All Exceptions.

Comment: @DougWatkins thank you for taking the time over this :) I've done that as well, and the debugger just keeps lopping back to main.m, `int main(int argc, char * argv[])`

Comment: Can you show the code for building the first scene?

Comment: @DougWatkins We're using an open source library this SlideNavigationController for the first scene. You can find the code here: https://github.com/aryaxt/iOS-Slide-Menu/blob/master/SlideMenu/Source/SlideNavigationController.m

Comment: In that case, I would put break points at all your objectAtIndex calls and see which one fires right before the crash. If none of them are the culprit then I would put in a bug request on the open sources page for people familiar with the project to debug.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76721/discussion-between-yvette-and-doug-watkins).

Comment: I actually don't really have anything else to look at without having the project to run and look at myself. If you can narrow down the area of code the fault is happening I may be able to help more though. Good luck, bugs suck.

Comment: You need to narrow down the potential cause. Which block(s) of code are being run when the crash occurs?